# vetur go to definition can't redirect after alt+click

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vetur

I am vue power user and I need in my project ALT+click (multiCursorModifier) on various vue component to jump into the definition/implementation.I have installed vetur and this is my
settings.json vetur specific settings.

```
   "vetur.experimental.templateInterpolationService": true,
   "vetur.trace.server": "verbose"
```

This is my jsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "@/*": ["./src/*"],
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I get when I click on my vue 2 component.

```
Unable to open 'vue-editor-bridge.ts': Unable to read file '\vue-temp\vue-editor-bridge.ts' (Error: Unable to resolve non-existing file '\vue-temp\vue-editor-bridge.ts').
```

All I want is click to definition to work. I have tried also vue peek extension with no success. How can I proceed further?

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your components as global components inside the vetur config file :

```
globalComponents: ['./components/**/*.vue']
```

More information in [the vetur doc](https://vuejs.github.io/vetur/guide/global-components.html#example).